# Failed to resolve: haibison.android:underdogs

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

Suddenly I received this error:

Error:Failed to resolve: haibison.android:underdogs:+
Open File
Show in Project Structure dialog

This is the build file:
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ro.demo.proj1"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 17
        versionName "1.0.17"
    }

    buildTypes {
        // Proguard Settings
        debug {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles '../proguard_dexguard_configs/proguard-android.txt', '../proguard_dexguard_configs/proguard-project.txt'
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles '../proguard_dexguard_configs/proguard-android.txt', '../proguard_dexguard_configs/proguard-project.txt'
        }
    }

    /*sourceSets {
         main {
             java {
                 exclude '**//*OpenCVUtils.java'
                 exclude '**//*Recognizer.java'
                 exclude '**//*BasicCropper.java'
             }
         }
     }*/

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
}

dependencies {

    compile 'com.joanzapata.pdfview:android-pdfview:1.0.4@aar'

    compile 'haibison.android:lockpattern:10.0.0'

}
```

Any feedback will be appreciated.

and the project build file is:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'http://haibison.bitbucket.org/maven-repos' }
        maven { url 'https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.amlcurran.showcaseview/library' }
        flatDir {
            dirs '../third_party_lib/aar'
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from https://bitbucket.org/haibison/android-lockpattern/wiki/Quick-Use, it looks like you also need to add following to your main `build.gradle`

```
repositories {
    ...
    maven { url 'https://haibison.bitbucket.io/maven-repos' }
}
```

Comment: When I added the above I was able to resolve that dependency here.

Comment: I had http reference instead of https but i cannot figure out how it worked until now

Comment: Same here @aurelianr , thought not only the http to https change, bitbucket.org also has been changed to bitbucket.io